# Calling finish() removes the activity from activity stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have made an application where I

1. start activity 'Pin' after I start `activity A`(activity A has `noHistory= true`, so it will not stay on stack).
2. If no pin has been set up; `PinActivity` also starts an activity `NewPinActivity`.
3. After setting pin, `NewPinActivity` calls `finish()` and goes back to  `PinActivity`. Where you will give appropriate pin, it will call `finish()` on it and it will move again to `activity A`(Since `activity A` had `noHistory=true`, so I have to start a new instance of `activity A`).
   My problem is, if I press `back` from `activity A`, sometimes my `NewPinActivity` shows up again even if I called `finish()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should use in a second activity:

```
        Intent exitIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        exitIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(exitIntent);
        MainActivity.exitHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

and in MainActivity:

```
    exitHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
            // clear any informations you like here
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is an interesting way of putting it. I have resolved my this problem but will try it in my code at other place.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be starting `NewPinActivity` using `startActivityForResult`. On a successful result `PinActivity` should launch `ActivityA` with `Intent.FLAG_NEW_INTENT` and `finish();` itself? Curiously why are you starting your `ActivityA` with noHistory?

Comment: activity A does some work which is crucial, which starts there only if my PinActivity returns to `activity A` with positive result(ie. pin answered correctly). That's why I have to start new instance of Activity A once I am done with PinActivity.

Comment: Ah I know what you need. ActivityA should call PinActivity with startActivityForResult and it should start NewPinActivity with the same except with the addition of the ` Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` flag.

Comment: Activity A has 'nohistory=true', so as soon as one leaves the activity it finishes. So 'startActivityForResult' will work? as the activity A who called this will be finish. So to which activity result will be delivered then?