# StartActivityForResult() and OnActivityResult() both needed?

Tags: android, onactivityresult, start-activity

Is it necessary to start an `Activity` with `startActivityForResult()` to set a result in second activity or,

one may start the `Activity` by normal `startActivity()` and still set a result in second `Activity` and get it back using `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: why would there be 2 methods if both did the same thing? and what value of `requestCode` would you expect? also, testing this shouldn't take more than 5 minutes and about 20 lines of code tops.

Comment: Answer lies in Antoine's comment. I checked it already, but I was puzzled if startActivityForResult() is the only way one can receive result in other activity then what is the use of `setResult()` in child activity if nobody can read it. 
Because I saw somebody's implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25057102/609782 so thought `setResult()` also has a way unknown to me that could be used to get results for parent activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Activity.onActivityResult` is a callback. It is different from `startActivity` and `startActivityForResult` because the response is asynchronous.

You can set the result of an `Activity` without requirement, but the method `onActivityResult` will only be called if the activity that 'resulted' was started with `startActivityForResult`.

So yes, if you want to start an activity and obtain a result, you need to first start it using `Activity.startActivityForResult`, then override `onActivityResult` and catching the result there.

Comment: So what is use of setting a result if I could not get it without startActivityForResult? Can it be read some other way?

Comment: The API is built around the idea that if you want to get a result, you know it and therefore start the activity using `startActivityForResult`. I can't see the use of an activity's result in other conditions, and the API has no `Activity.getResult` method, only a `setResult` one.

Comment: @Darpan if you already are overriding `onActivityResult` to obtain the result, there nothing to prevent you to call `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

You can get result from this activity only if you start it with `startActivityForResult()`